# Run startx from a ubuntu docker container on ubuntu host OS, blank screen with an X icon in the center show up

Tags: 14.04, xorg, xserver, docker

I had an ubuntu docker image that have installed ubuntu-desktop package.

Started it on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS host OS (an Ubuntu VM) by command :

```
sudo docker run -it --privileged *IMAGE_NAME* bin/bash
```

Since I have ubuntu-desktop package installed, inside the container I start an X server by run command :

```
startx
```

A blank screen showed up with an "X" icon in the center:
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mx6DI.png)

Can some one explain what going on under the hood ? Why does this happen ?